# SSL Handshake exception - RESTEASY004655

Tags: java, ssl, sslhandshakeexception

I am trying to figure out why am having this type of exception all over the log file!!!!

Looking on some internet posts, apparently they talk about network interruption !!!

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:287)
    at com.agfa.orbis.core.client.service.rest.ClientHttpEngineWrapper.invoke(ClientHttpEngineWrapper.java:59)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:436)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:471)
    at com.agfa.hap.base.server.ServerValidationRestCalls.getDatabase(ServerValidationRestCalls.java:51)
    at com.agfa.hap.base.server.ServerValidationRestCalls.getDatabaseIdentifier(ServerValidationRestCalls.java:101)
    at com.agfa.hap.base.server.ClientServerDBConsistence.determineServerDBIdentifier(ClientServerDBConsistence.java:148)
    at com.agfa.hap.base.server.ClientServerDBConsistence.isClientAndIndividualServerDBIdentical(ClientServerDBConsistence.java:230)
    at com.agfa.hap.base.server.ServerConnectionManager.isClientAndIndividualServerDBIdentical(ServerConnectionManager.java:329)
    at com.agfa.hap.base.server.ServerConnectionManager.checkAppServerDatabaseConsistency(ServerConnectionManager.java:286)
    at com.agfa.hap.base.server.ServerConnectionManager.executeServerConnectionReview(ServerConnectionManager.java:202)
    at com.agfa.hap.base.server.ServerConnectionManager.checkServerConnection(ServerConnectionManager.java:175)
    at com.agfa.hap.base.server.ServerConnectionManager$2.run(ServerConnectionManager.java:259)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:992)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:535)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:403)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:283)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
    ... 28 more
```

Any clue about such exception ?

Comment: Have you checked the certificate for validity (like date and servername)? What happens when you visit the URI with a browser?

Comment: I think that an invalid cert would give a different exception message

Comment: Typing the URI directly via a web browser gives a good Response, as the certificate is valid on both peers !!

Answer (score 4):

It isn't a network interruption (or an invalid / expired SSL cert).  What has happened is the remote end has closed the connection in the middle of the SSL connection negotiation.  Most likely it is because there is a mismatch between requested and supported protocol versions or crypto algorithms.

You need to turn on debugging messages for the SSL protocol stack; e.g. using `-Djavax.net.debug=all`.  That will give you more information, and from that you can figure out what you need to do to fix the mismatch.